# register-job-definition in AWS Batch giving "RegisterJobDefinition operation: Error executing request, Exception : The validated object is null"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

```html
aws --region us-east-1 batch register-job-definition --job-definition-name test-job-defn-5 --type container --container-properties '{"image": "ACCOUNT-ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/batch-experiment-job:latest","memory": 2048}'
```

is giving the following error:

```
An error occurred (ClientException) when calling the RegisterJobDefinition operation: Error executing request, Exception : The validated object is null, RequestId: 9e9a169f-***
```

I have also tried the python boto3 library, and get the same error. I have permissions for I can create Job Queues and Compute Environments successfully.

I have followed the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/batch/register-job-definition.html and
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/batch.html#Batch.Client.register_job_definition but don't seen to identify what the issue is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the issue. The `vcpus` parameter is REQUIRED, even though the documentation doesn't list it that way.

Comment: Hi @ManishJain. I'm confused by the documentation. Under documentation for                 `vcpus` and `memory` it says "This parameter is deprecated, use `resourceRequirements`". When I set `resourceRequirements` parameter, I get the error message 'unknown parameter in input: "resourceRequirements"'. Would you be able to provide me with your code for registering a job defenition?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to the other answer, but you also need to specify the memory too. I was the opposite, I specified the vCPUs, but not the memory